# Using grunt.js along with require.js to concat, minify, and inject javascript/css inline into HTML document

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

Perhaps my google-fu is failing me today, however I am looking for an example/way to configure grunt.js to insert the contents of the post-compile javascript (and CSS) into the final rendered HTML document (to help with load/render times).

Has anyone done this, or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin). With this task you can add comments to your head around your script/style tags. The task will find all sources between the start/end of the comment and concat/minify/build requirejs for this files

```
<!-- build:js build/js/app.js -->
<script src="js/controllers/thing-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/thing-model.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/thing-view.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This block for example will result in a file `app.js` holding all the minified/concatenated files and create a new html file that replace the block with `<script src="build/js/app.js"></script>`

Comment: Does this place nice with RequireJS? I believe they are depreciating requireJS support, but I'm not sure. Is there another requirejs specific solution?

Comment: No. It does not play nice with grunt-contrib-requirejs. grunt-contrib-requirejs a more full solution and you would waste time implementing usemin only to have it superseded.